# Confusion about absolute value, exponents, and logarithms

Tags: integration, logarithms, absolute-value

Problem 1:

> $\int \tan x\, dx$

The answer in the book is $-\ln |(\cos x)|+C$. I used the following steps:
$$\ln |\sec x|+C$$
$$\ln |(\cos x)^{-1}|+C$$
$$-\ln |(\cos x)|+C$$

Problem 2:

> $\int \frac{\sin 2x}{1-\cos 2x}\, dx$

The answer in the book is $\ln \sqrt{|1-\cos 2x|}+C$. I used the following steps:
$$u=1-\cos 2x$$
$$dx=\frac{du}{2\sin 2x}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u}\, du$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln |1-\cos 2x|+C$$
Here is where I get confused. Based on problem 1, $\frac{1}{2}\ln |1-\cos 2x|+C$ should equal $\ln |\sqrt{1-\cos 2x}|+C$ but it must equal $\ln \sqrt{|1-\cos 2x|}+C$ because that's the correct answer. So what is the rule when turning the number in front of a logarithm into an exponent when an absolute value is in the logarithm argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1-\cos \, t \geq 0$ for all real numbers $t$ so absolute values signs are unnecessary in your answer as well as the given answer. So the two answers are the same.

Comment: Can the exponent be placed either inside of the absolute value bars or outside of the bars? Is that the general rule?

Comment: $|\sqrt a|=\sqrt {|a|}$ is true whenever the square root is defined as a real number. This is because  $\sqrt a$ exists as  a real number only when $a \geq 0$ and $\sqrt a$ is then a non-negative number also.

Comment: What about for any other power besides 1/2?

Comment: True for any postive power: $|x^{a}|=|x|^{a}$ for all $a>0$ for all real $x$.

Comment: True for $\frac 1 2$ also as long  you are not using expressions that are not defined, like square roots of negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in\mathbb R$, then $1-\cos(2x)\geqslant0$. Therefore,$$\ln\sqrt{\big\lvert1-\cos(2x)\bigr\rvert}=\ln\left(\left\lvert\sqrt{1-\cos(2x)}\right\rvert\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{1-\cos(2x)}\right).$$

Comment: Does $-\ln |(\cos x)|+C=\ln |(\cos x)^{-1}|+C=\ln |(\cos x)|^{-1}+C$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: But $\cos x$ is not greater than or equal to zero

Comment: Can the exponent be placed either inside of the absolute value bars or outside of the bars? Is that the general rule?

Comment: Yes: $\lvert a\rvert^b=\lvert a^b\rvert$.